# Fixing image urls after nightmare WP migration

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm at the tail-end of a nightmare WP migration. Got everything working except a bunch of broken image links, which I've tracked down to a repeating token.

example (broken) URL is:

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/reset.gif

and the actual gif is located in:

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/06/reset.gif

With hundreds of such instances I thought the easiest solution would be a RewriteRule in the .htaccess file to handle the redirect, but I can't nail down the regex to handle it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not tested: `RewriteRule ^(/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/[0-9]{4}/)([0-9]{2}/)(.*) $1$2$2$3 [R,L]`

Answer (score 1):

[You don't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)

Following the regex suggested by Sato Katsura (i.e. I haven't tested the match) you could do this, as suggested by the linked wiki page:

```
RedirectMatch ^(/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/[0-9]{4}/)([0-9]{2}/)(.*) $1$2$2$3
```

Answer (score 0):

The example provided needs the month twice, so you could get along with:

```
\/(\d+)\/.+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jA1jJ0/1).
In terms of `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(\d+)\/(.+)$ $1/$2/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

See a demo for the [**replacement on regex101.com as well**](https://regex101.com/r/jA1jJ0/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Search & Replace plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) ( or [interconnectit database search and replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) ) before tampering with `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`. Tools like that are essential for fixing broken links during transfer or a migration of an WordPress.

The location of the image files uploaded through the WordPress media upload system is in `wp_postmeta` table. The problem is therefore in the database and there should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while I migrated WP Website to the new server. Following should help you and let me know if you still face any more troubles

1. just you need to ensure your root folder has Acess permission as 755 Permissions.
2. You should add the below lines in your wpconfig.php file in your wp root-

   ```
   define('WP_HOME','https://covid19.pinlocos.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','https://covid19.pinlocos.com');
   ```
3. Add a .htaccess file with the following details:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
   ErrorDocument 404 index.php
   ```